# Check if key / value pair exist within another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have the following two objects (Object A and Object B), how can I check if Object B's key/value exists with Object A? In the below example it should return True because both 'make: "Apple"' and 'Model: "iPad"' exists in Object A.

**Edit:** Object B will be dynamic and may contain only Make or only Model. More keys are added dynamically via checkbox filters.

Is it easier to use a library such as Underscore? If so what functions would be applicable?

I hope this makes sense?

```
        var a = {
            Make: "Apple",
            Model: "iPad",
            hasScreen: "yes",
            Review: "Great product!",
        }

        var b = {
            Make: "Apple",
            Model: "iPad"
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, it needs to be a dynamic loop somehow

Comment: in the case of your edit, `b.Make` would just be undefined and the comparison would just return false. `a.Make === b.Make` still makes sense.

Comment: Ok cool but what if I added other properties in the future. Any way to make it work for unknown keys?

Comment: `function compareKeys(a,b,key){ return a[key] === b[key]; }` or something

Comment: you can find this two posts helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160998/compare-two-json-arrays-in-jquery-or-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094062/jquery-comparing-and-find-out-the-difference-between-2-json-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over all keys and check if the values are equal.

```js
var a = { Make: "Apple", Model: "iPad", hasScreen: "yes", Review: "Great product!" },
    b = { Make: "Apple", Model: "iPad" },
    every = Object.keys(b).every(function (k) {
        return a[k] === b[k];
    });

document.write(every);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina - perfect... :-)

Answer (score 2):

There’s no builtin way of doing this, but you can use your own implementation (see Nina Scholz’ answer) or Lodash’s [_.isMatch](https://lodash.com/docs#isMatch) function (or [Underscore’s _.isMatch](http://underscorejs.org/#isMatch)):

```
_.isMatch(a, b)
```